# Match "com.project.name" but not when it contains something else

Tags: swift, regex, regex-negation, swiftlint

I have the following code:

```
var i = "test"
```

and

```
var i = "com.project.name.test"

print("something else")
fatalError("some error")
```

**I have a regex:**

```
"((?!com\.project\.name).)*"
```

to match any string that does NOT contain `"com.project.name"`.

However, I want to modify it to still have the above condition but not if the line contains `print\(.*?\)` and `fatalError\(.*?\)`.

Why do I want to do this? Because I can only use regex for SwiftLint custom rules and right now my regex is greedy and matches every single string in the project that the developers forgot to localize..

**What I've tried:**

`"((?!com\\.project\\.name).)*(?!print)(?!fatalError)"`

but it does not work and instead matches the same as the original expression.

Comment: Try this: `^(?!.*(?:com\.project\.name|print|fatalError)).*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this regex with a negative lookahead assertions:

```
^(?!.*(?:com\.project\.name|print\(|fatalError\()).*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/emsHG1/1)

This negative lookahead assertion uses alternations to fail the match on 3 different matches anywhere in the input:

1. `com\.project\.name`
2. `print\(`
3. `fatalError\(`